# Can multiple Docker containers run using the same host/port?

Tags: docker, port

Been looking into using Docker for a REST service project. One question I have is whether we could use Docker to run multiple versions of the service on the same host/port.

For example, I want to have an endpoint at {myserver}:8080/v1/ and another at {myserver}:8080/v2/.

If it's relevant at all, these would be Java:8 based Docker images constructed with a java jar on the Spring Boot REST framework.

Is this possible with Docker containers?

Comment: this is a XY problem. this is possible without containers using a proxy (e.g. nginx). containers are irrelevant here; you can run the backend services in containers... or not.

Comment: It's an interesting question tough, because Docker could have integrated a small proxy feature for routes. Imagine something like: one container with Apache, the other one with Node.js working both on :80 without need of a proxy...

Answer (score 9):

You can run both containers using different host ports, and use a haproxy/nginx/varnish (native or inside another container) listening to the host port, and redirecting to the right container based on the URL.

Comment: For Nginx the following nginx-proxy solution with docker-gen could help: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy You basically add a proxy in your docker environment and let it handle the requests on your host port and forward it to the appropriate container

Answer (score 7):

This is as much a question about the way tcp ports work as the way docker works. In the same way that two applications can't bind to the same tcp port, neither can two docker containers.

As @Sergei Rodionov points out SO_REUSEPORT can be used to allow multiple processes to share the same tcp port (and this can be specified when launching your java application). I don't think this will work across containers.

Comment: What if the initial socket is bound with SO_REUSEPORT option?

Comment: It seems to me that SO_REUSEPORT is meant to be used for processes on the same machine. Do you think it would work across containers?

Comment: @RobertMoskal For Nginx the following nginx-proxy solution with docker-gen could help: github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy You basically add a proxy in your docker environment and let it handle the requests on your host port and forward it to the appropriate container

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible as long as you are using different network addresses for each duplicate port you are listening on.

For example, your host has the following IPs assigned to it:
192.168.11.223
10.88.88.12

You could have two separate containers both listening on:
192.168.11.223:80
10.88.88.12:80

If you look at the syntax for docker run:

```
-p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host 
             format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort
             Both hostPort and containerPort can be specified as a range of ports. 
             When specifying ranges for both, the number of container ports in the range must match the number of host ports in the range. (e.g., `-p 1234-1236:1234-1236/tcp`)
             (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is possible as long as containers are using different IP address. 
you can check the IP address of the containers by using below command.

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <container ID>
```

Comment: This IP address is an internal implementation detail of Docker, and it won't be accessible from other hosts.