# Docker aws port

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers, port

I'm new using docker. 
I was asking me if is possible to run many containers on the same `aws ec2` instance, triggering all port of the containers on one sigle port on the ec2 instance.

Suppose that we have 3 container:

- `container1` that run  `apache2 on port 80`
- `container2` that run  `nginx on port 80`
- `container3` with `tomcat on port 8080`

How can access to these services from my pc? 
To do this I read that I need to expose ports by typing option `-p externport : containerport` but its not working 
so i thought  to  change network and then I use option `--network=host` to trig all port to the same ip but it doesn't work.

I'd like just to accesso to these container in this way:

- my-ec2-instance-public-dns:8080 -> container1
- my-ec2-instance-public-dns:8081 -> container2
- my-ec2-instance-public-dns:8082 -> container3

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple Docker containers run using the same host/port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958292/can-multiple-docker-containers-run-using-the-same-host-port)

Comment: Can you share your actual `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file?  Sharing a single port, no, not without some sort of proxy layer; on separate ports, trivial application of `docker run -p`; both topics should be fairly readily searchable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to map two services to the same port. You can map container ports to host ports using the -p flag, formatted hostPort:containerPort when you use [container networking mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

In your case, it could be

```
docker run -p 8080:80 nginx
docker run -p 8081:80 apache2
docker run -p 8082:8080 tomcat
```

Make sure you set the AWS security group of your virtual machine to allow traffic from your IP to ports 8080-8082.

Comment: if i do this and give image name i.e `docker run -p 8080:80 <image_name>` , it creates new container of same iage, I want o connect with running container only how can I do that ?