# Mapping ports from two different containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to map ports from two different containers a bit like the way we map a host port to a container port.

Basically I have my application running in `container-1` and I have a nginx running in `container-2`.

What I want to accomplish is being able to listen to all the traffic going to `container-1:80` on `container-2:80` so that in my `nginx.conf` file when I have `listen 80` I will actually be receiving traffic from `container-1:80`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  (And if you're using nginx as a proxy, how would it forward the traffic on to the real `container-1`?)  I'd just reconfigure my other containers to talk to `container-2`.

Comment: I want to use `container-2` as a reverse proxy. I want my application to run in a container then get the traffic in another which will then forward it to a third one where I would do some processing on the data received

Comment: You shouldn't need to any strange traffic interception things.  Just configure your hypothetical sending `container-3` to send to `container-2` instead of `container-1`.

Answer (score 0):

this question has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958292/can-multiple-docker-containers-run-using-the-same-host-port)!

two applications can't bind to the same tcp port, neither can two docker containers.

Comment: Sorry that's not my question. I don't want to link to the host not even the same port. I just want a way to bind the port from one container to another. The host will not be involved

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your objective is but I have a suggestion:

You can communicate with container-2 from container-1 if they are on the same docker network, more on docker networks:

https://docs.docker.com/network/#scope-of-this-topic

And container communication here:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/

You can user the container name to resolve the address of the other container, just make sure you're exposing the port in the Dockerfile

Comment: Basically between a container and the host I can just do `-p 80:80` and I can receive all the traffic sent to host port 80 in the container. So I want to to something similar with two containers. My goal is to have `container-2` as a reverse proxy. My application will run in `container-1` then I can get the traffic in `container-2` which will then forward it to `container-3` where I would do some processing on the data received

Comment: Then you don't need to expose the port. The containers will be able to communicate with each other as long as they're running on the same docker machine (I assume you're using your laptop). Example of 2 docker containers witn an nginx reverse proxy here: https://medium.com/@itseranga/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-docker-c9ead938fffd  as you can see in the nginx configuration you can refer to the "container-1" by it's name, in this case "web". You can read more on container communication here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/

Comment: Thanks for the infos. This is kind of the setup I currently have with physical machines. I think my issue is that none of my containers are communicating with the outside world. All my requests are sent from within `container-1` not from the host otherwise this would have been the perfect solution for me.